# docker container curl from one container to another

Tags: nginx, docker-compose

I have four containers A,B,C and D. container C is an nginx container which is configure to serve container A and B and D. Iam in container D and want to curl contaner B but i can't get through.

on my docker-compose file, I expose port 1000:1000 on container B. In container C the ngnix default.conf file is configure to accept connection on port 70 for container B. I can access container_B from http://localhost:70. But i try curl -v container_B:70 from container D and i get the error
curl: (7) Failed to connect to container_B port 70: Connection refused

when i try curl -v container_B:9000
I get:

```html
*   Trying 172.27.0.4:9000...
* Connected to container_B (172.27.0.4) port 9000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: auth-api:9000
> User-Agent: curl/7.74.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

nginx config

```html
server {
    listen 70;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/html/container_B/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass  container_B:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

compose file

```html
container_A:
    image: test/container_A:1.0
    container_name:  container_A
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - main_db
      
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME:  container_A
    working_dir: /var/www/html/
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    volumes:
      - ./container_A:/var/www/html

    networks:
      - back-tier
      - front-tier
 
  container_B:
    image: test/container_B:1.0
    container_name:  container_B
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - auth_db
      - backend_api
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME:container_B
    ports:
      - 1000:1000
    volumes:
      - ./container_B:/var/www/html/container_B
    networks:
      - back-tier
      - front-tier
      
      
  
  container_D:
    image: test/container_d:1.0
    container_name:  container_D
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - backend_api
      - container_B
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME:  container_D
    ports:
      - 6000:6000
    volumes:
      - ./ container_D:/var/www/html/container_D
    
    networks:
      - front-tier
      
      
      
    container_c:
    image: test/nginx:1.0
    depends_on:
      - backend_api
      - container_B
      - main_db
    container_name: container_c
    restart: always
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "70:70"
      - "60:60"
      - "50:50"
    networks:
      - front-tier
      - back-tier
```

Comment: Are you running your curl command from inside container C ? That should work fine. From your local machine not.

Comment: I am running it from container D

Comment: @Chai i can curl container_B from container C, but i cannot curl container_B from container D. I want to be able to curl Container_B from container D.

Comment: Ok. I assume all of them are in the same docker-compose, or at least in the same network? Maybe post the full docker-compose, just to see if anyone sees something that might help ?

Comment: all in docker-compose and same network. i have updated the docker compose

Comment: Your docker compose as posted has multiple errors and is as such not a minimal working example. I made an adaptation: https://pastebin.com/aH3UZ13U . This works with curl etc. So I think your basic setup is fine, you just have errors somewhere where we can not help you because the code posted is not exactly the code you have, or it would not even let you start the containers.

Comment: @Chai do you think nginx might be causing the issue?

Comment: No because curl does not have anything to do with nginx. It seems a networking issue. Are you managing your networks in the same docker-compose ? Maybe post your real docker-compose if possible, or at least make a working example to show your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to figure out what i was doing wrong. Since the service that i want to curl in container B is running on an instance of container C which is an nginx container serving the three containers. I was suppose to curl -v container_C:70. Port 70 is the port that is configure in default.conf nginx file that is listening on container B.

What i did wrong was trying to curl to container B directly that is why i was encounter the error curl: (7) Failed to connect to container_B port 70: Connection refused. Because the instance that i was trying to connect to wasn't running on container B.